# How to share link to social media like facebook, twitter, instagram without redirect to social platform

Tags: flutter, dart

I  want to share link to social media like facebook, twitter, Instagram but  without redirect to social paltform.

I have tried:

I used social_share_plugin,share,flutter_share_me and flutter_social_content_share package but all redirect to social paltforms.

FlutterSocialContentShare.share(
type: ShareType.instagramWithImageUrl,
imageUrl:
"https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/healthy-eating-ingredients-732x549-thumbnail-732x549.jpg");

Comment: could you share some code for us please?

Comment: FlutterSocialContentShare.share( type: ShareType.instagramWithImageUrl, imageUrl: "https://post.healthline.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/healthy-eating-ingredients-732x549-thumbnail-732x549.jpg");